Embedding multiple reports in powerbi appowns github sample application
currently i am embedding 1 powerbi report in the sample app . How to embedd multiple reports from the workspace. Following is the sample code of my html file with report container:
<h2>Embedded Report</h2>
<div id="embedContainer"></div>
<script>

    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
    const reportContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

    powerbi.bootstrap(reportContainer, { type: 'report' });

    const accessToken = "@Model.EmbedToken.Token";
    const embedUrl = "@Html.Raw(Model.EmbedReports[0].EmbedUrl)";
    const embedReportId = "@Model.EmbedReports[0].ReportId";
    const tokenExpiry = "@Model.EmbedToken.Expiration";
    const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    const config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedReportId,
        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
        settings: {
            // background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    };

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    const report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
</script>

